# how to get the native app font type or style using UI Automation JavaScript Reference for iOS appium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, appium, appium-ios

I have to test a native app using appium ios. In one of my test case my scenario is to get the Text font type or font size.

I use

```
.getCssValue("font-size")
```

but this does not work as the app does not have web view.
Now i am trying to get this by using

```
UI Automation JavaScript Reference for iOS
```

i use the below code to get it:

```
 String name = (String) driver.executeScript("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().navigationBar().staticTexts()[0].fontName()");
```

but this does not work. I have stucked in this problem. Please help.

Comment: what does `.getCssValue("font")` return to you?

Comment: I used .getCssValue("font") but it returns the error like this -

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not implemented in this context, try switching into or out of a web view (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).

Our app has only one context that is NATIVE_APP and it doesn't provide any web view. How can I get the solution for this

Comment: could you please share the screenshot of appium inspector with all the attributes of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to get font size of the element at the moment, just because it does not supported by [XCUIElementAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes), so Appium that uses XCUITest as iOS framework has no possibility as well